# How the apps already build for iPhone 4 and 5 will shown in iPhone 6 and 6 plus

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

As the apple has announced the two more screen sizes iPhone 6 and 6 plus. What will happen to apps already in app store build for iPhone 4 and 5. Will they be stretched or their layout be distorted in these new phones?

Please help me because I have recently submitted two of my apps in app store waiting for review. So should I change them or they will work fine. As I haven't use Auto layout in these apps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have uploaded apps from XCode 5.x apple will take care and they will be scaled and stretched to fit them in iPhone and iPhone 6. If you want to take advantage of new devices you will have to use XCode 6 and add launch images on your project with [these steps](http://matthewpalmer.net/blog/2014/09/10/iphone-6-plus-launch-image-adaptive-mode/).

If you have not added launch images for iPhone 6 and 6 plus (and do not have `Launch Screen File` for iOS 8) , than your apps will be streached to fit in new devices , once you add them app will not be streached and you will have to manage it.

So with Xcode 5.x , you can be absoulatly sure that iOS will take care and streach your app to look just like thy look in iPhone 5 or 5S.

Answer (score 2):

As Bhumit said, you need to add launch images at the new sizes if you want to have your apps scale properly for iPhone 6.

A corollary is that they will **not scale in the simulator** until you add those launch images. You can just add some default ones to test - I recommend grabbing [David Smith's blanks](https://twitter.com/_davidsmith/status/509500836293378048).

If you do not test in the simulator with launch images, you will get a false impression of your app working because the default scaling kicks in. (If you are happy to leave it with that default scaling, fine for now.)

Comment: I have these images. They still don't scale.

Comment: Double-check how you are specifying that the images are used by your project, just having them in the folder is not enough. Also, after changing assets or other project settings, I often find forcing a rebuild is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

According to the latest version of **Xcode 6** , the apps running in the previous iPhone environments of 5 and 4s will work as they are in iOS 8 i.e **iPhone 6 , 6+**. I suggest you **download** Xcode 6 from the **Apple Developer Site** and run your apps in the iPhone 6 and 6+ and see for yourself.

Comment: But the aspect ratio of phones has been changed so it must affect the app's views ratio. (sorry I can't install the xcode 6 right now because of some constrains) please clarify it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found the [apple link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html) for this problem. Under heading 'Supporting New Screen Sizes and Scales'. You can check out above link for more such information.