# Will I need to add more horizontal constraints to old apps just so my apps look the same on new iPhone 6?

Tags: iphone, ios7, constraints, ios8

The new iPhone 6 dimensions are a bit confusing to me. Before the iPhone 6, the width was always 320 pixels (to my knowledge), so positioning buttons horizontally to dynamically look good on all iPhones prior to iPhone 6 was not hard. Now with this new width change (no longer 320 pixels in width, do we have to start adding horizontal constraints to our buttons? Or am I overlooking something obvious? What about all the apps out there prior to iPhone 6? When these apps are opened on an iPhone 6 I imagine a lot of them are going to look off?

Answer (score 0):

The apps which are not targeted for iPhone 6 and are developed in xcode 5.1 will not have any affect on its aspect ratio as mentioned in [apple link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html). Under heading 'Supporting New Screen Sizes and Scales'. But if you are including the iPhone 6 launch images and targeting the iPhone 6, 6 plus and lower devices then yes you should take care of horizontal constrains also. you can also check out the answers of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930216/how-the-apps-already-build-for-iphone-4-and-5-will-shown-in-iphone-6-and-6-plus) may be it will help you.