# i am trying to get iPhone 6 screen size in simulator but it showing the wrong dimensions

Tags: ios, screen-size, xcode6.1, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

Here u see the **Width as 320** and **Height as 568** but it is wrong because i am running in **iPhone 6** and **iPhone 6 Plus** simulators. Any one of you know why it happens like this. I Reset the simulator and tried there is no change.

This is for iPhone 6 Plus
[image]

This is for iPhone 6 
  [image]

Comment: Have you added a launch xib or appropriately sized launch image?

Comment: Actually project started in xcode5 long ago.. so, Used appropriately sized launch image, Prasad

Comment: it is giving your storyboard view size. use auto layout for diff screens

Comment: issue is resolved, after add launch screens for iPhone 6 and 6 plus thankq "Prasad" "Mats" @iHulk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until you will not add the launch image for iPhone 6 and 6 plus it will not resize your views according to the iPhone 6 and 6 plus but it will return it as of iPhone 5.

It is because if your app is build on xcode 5 using the ios version less than 8.0, apple will take care and they will be scaled and stretched to fit them in iPhone6 and iPhone 6 plus. If you want to take advantage of new devices you will have to uadd launch images on your project. find the [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930216/how-the-apps-already-build-for-iphone-4-and-5-will-shown-in-iphone-6-and-6-plus) it will clear your doubt.